# Paging 2 different entity collections together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using entity framework core.  I have two dbsets that both inherit from same parent class like this.

```
public abstract class Salary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public decimal RegularRate { get; set; }
    public decimal OvertimeRate { get; set; }    

}

public class AdvertisedSalary : Salary
{
    //additional properties
}

public class NegotiatedSalary : Salary
{
    //additional properties
}
```

I have created the usual code for paginating these entities in my endpoints using `Skip()` and this works fine on the frontend where each entity is displayed in it's own grid.

I have been given the requirement to create a filterable, sortable and pagable grid that includes both `AdvertisedSalary` and `NegotiatedSalary` in the same grid. I only have to show the base class properties but what is throwing me out is how can I paginate this?

For instance, lets say the create date filter is active and page size is 10.  I could get the first 10 from each dbset then send back the newest 10 but what about if they request the 8th page?  The only way I can think to do it is to create 2 collections that include every record in the two dbsets, cast to base class then order it and return the right page.  This would be a really intensive task and defeats purpose of paging the results.

Is this the only way to do it?  Is there a way to order two different dbsets together by date and then return the right results with `Skip()` or similar?

Comment: Maybe cache the result with something like this: https://github.com/VahidN/EFSecondLevelCache.Core/

Comment: I suppose if i put all records into a cache it would save subsequent requests but i'd still have to pull back all records and then manage invalidating it if user takes an action on an item which they will be doing often.

Comment: One way of looking at it is that it's impossible to filter and paginate two different sets of data. That doesn't mean that the problem is impossible - it just means that the first step is having a single set of data. One way might be a stored procedure with a union.

Comment: Ahh, union seems to be what I need thanks.  I haven't really used it before but if I can use union to join the two tables then I can use skip() to paginate.  Not sure exactly on performance aspect. I will read up on it.

Comment: Are you using EF inheritance? In other words, is `Salary` an entity or is just a base class and derived entities use separate tables with their own PKs etc.?

Comment: Salary is an abstract base class I use to keep child properties the same.  It doesn't have its own dbset

Comment: Write the query with `Union` with selecting common fields from two tables. There is no need to write stored procedure in which you will do exact same thing. Apply what you want to this query: OrderBy, Skip, Take and so on. And  the datasource of your grid would be the result query. Performance will be normal if you are using indexes on tables.

Comment: @HemidAbbasov Thanks for the advice, could you elaborate on the indexes.  Do all common columns need to be indexes?

Comment: @Guerrilla, indexes - is a pretty big topic. But there is, let's say, a small set of mandatory indixes: the index for the primary key field(s) (could be created automatically when creating the key); index on the field(s) of the foreign key; index on the fields by which the tables are joined (when tables are joined without using pare of  "primary key - foreign key" ); index on the fields that are most often used in the `where` clause of sql queries. You can search for articles that tell "what are the indexes for and when it is necessary to use them" or have a consultation with db admin.